# Filter condition on multiple Join / Inner Join SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to perform a SQL query with the best possible performance.

First of all I want to randomly pick among the 30000 results a city then JOIN the results another table with the condition

```
ON `r1`.`ville_nom_reel` = `r3`.`full_name`
```

(Based on the same city name).
To this query I would like to add a filter to display only the results of which

```
r1`.`ville_population_2012` > 10000
```

Here is my main query: run in approximately 0.010 sec.

```
  SELECT * FROM `inspitravel`.`villes_france_free` AS `r1` 
  JOIN (SELECT CEIL(RAND() * (SELECT MAX(`ville_id`) FROM `inspitravel`.`villes_france_free`)) AS `ville_id` ) AS `r2` USING (`ville_id`)
  INNER JOIN `inspitravel`.`villes_booking` AS `r3`
  ON `r1`.`ville_nom_reel` = `r3`.`full_name`
```

How do I filter these results with this condition please?

```
`r1`.`ville_population_2012` > 10000
```

Comment: What would make you think this is a French language site?  Did you see any posts in French?

Comment: As for your question, have you tried adding `WHERE r1.ville_population_2012 > 10000` ?

Comment: I removed the SQL Server tag.  This is clearly MySQL.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen What would make you think this a proper way to warn someone on good behaviors ? Are you the Sherif or something else here ? I don't think so. So calm down ! My bad ! Next time, I will talk to you with my beautiful English.

Comment: @PabloDelaNoche J'aime le français, mais pas sur Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would start with a query that works:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT vff.*
      FROM inspitravel.villes_france_free vff
      WHERE ville_population_2012 > 10000
      ORDER BY rand()
      LIMIT 1
     ) vff JOIN
     inspitravel.villes_booking vb
     ON vff.ville_nom_reel = vb.full_name;
```

You can improve the performance of this query with an index on `villes_france_free(ville_population_2012)`.

Then, a safe way to reduce the run-time of this query is to use `rand()` in the `WHERE` clause.  For instance, you can use this to reduce the size of the sort by about 90%:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT vff.*
      FROM inspitravel.villes_france_free vff
      WHERE ville_population_2012 > 10000 AND
            rand() < 0.1
      ORDER BY rand()
      LIMIT 1
     ) vff JOIN
     inspitravel.villes_booking vb
     ON vff.ville_nom_reel = vb.full_name;
```

However, the exact value to choose depends on the number of matching towns.

Something like this would normally work:

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT vff.*
      FROM inspitravel.villes_france_free vff CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt FROM inspitravel.villes_france_free vff WHERE ville_population_2012 > 10000
           ) x
      WHERE ville_population_2012 > 10000 AND
            (cnt < 100 OR rand() < 0.1 * cnt)
      ORDER BY rand()
      LIMIT 1
     ) vff JOIN
     inspitravel.villes_booking vb
     ON vff.ville_nom_reel = vb.full_name;
```

Comment: Thank you very much : The last one works very well (about 0.086 sec) !! I think it will take me two weeks at least to understand this query now :-)